# Polymer: change mandatory field empty-message

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

There is a simple Polymer form with mandatory input and a submit button.

```
<form id="foo-form" is="iron-form" method="post">
  <paper-input value="Foo text" required></paper-input>
  <paper-button onclick="_submit(event)">Submit</paper-button>
<form>
...
<script>
  function _submit(event) {
    Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
  }
</script>
```

Once Submit button is hit, the popup-messages got shown saying "Please fill out this field".

**Question:** how does one change this message?

Checked this link with no luck: https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse

Comment: You could also disable the browser's native form validation UI with [<`iron-form`>.disableNativeValidationUi](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form#property-disableNativeValidationUi), and then set [`<paper-input>.errorMessage`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-errorMessage). That would allow you to control the styling of the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `myInput.setCustomValidity('My custom error message!')` on your input.

This is an HTML5 feature: [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API's_element.setCustomValidity())